# Facebook social plugin comments notification

Tags: facebook, notifications, comments

I have added the Facebook social plugin comments on my site. When I get notification about the new facebook comments on my site, how do I tell on which page the comment has been made. I have hundreds of pages on my site with facebook comments.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1LDO.jpg

Like in this image above. It is only showing the comment, but I cant tell on which article/page this comment has been posted. Is there some way to find out ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the timestamp of the comment.

Comment: lol why didnt they make the comment itself click able. Why the time stamp *scratching my head real hard. Thanks Mathew.